# Examples of Artistic Works with Mathematical Aspects

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, arts

There are many examples of artistic works which have some mathematical aspects. A high school or undergraduate math teacher can use them as interesting examples in his/her teaching. e.g. In a combinatorics course when a teacher introduces the notion of a magic square, he/she can add examples form paintings and literature as follows:

**(1)** [Albrecht Dürer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_D%C3%BCrer)'s magic square in his famous painting [*Melancolia I*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melencolia_I)

[image]

**(2)** [Goethe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goethe)'s description of a magic square in [*Faust*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goethe%27s_Faust):

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
\text{Du musst verstehen!} & \text{You shall see, then! } \\
\text{Aus Eins mach Zehn,} & \text{From one make ten!} \\
\text{Und Zwei lass gehen,} & \text{Let two go again,} \\
\text{Und Drei mach gleich} & \text{Make three even,} \\
\text{So bist du reich.} & \text{You’re rich again.} \\
\text{Verlier die Vier!} & \text{Take away four!     } \\
\text{Aus Fünf und Sechs,} & \text{From five and six,} \\
\text{So sagt die Hex,} & \text{So says the Witch,} \\
\text{Mach Sieben und Acht,} & \text{Make seven and eight,} \\
\text{So ist's vollbracht:} & \text{So it’s full weight:} \\
\text{Und Neun ist Eins,} & \text{And nine is one,  } \\
\text{Und Zehn ist keins.} & \text{And ten is none.} \\
\text{Das ist das Hexen-Einmaleins!} & \text{This is the Witch’s one-times-one!} \\
\end{array}$$
(See [Faust](http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/German/FaustIScenesIVtoVI.htm), line 2540.)

Note that the above phrases are describing a magic square as follows:

[image]

**Question:** What are interesting examples of using mathematical notions in arts which are useful to introduce these notions to students at high school/undergraduate level?

Comment: I remember seeing an interesting picture of the $3$-adic disk interpreted in Koblitz's book on $p$-adic numbers: http://i.imgur.com/ffcYMej.jpg This is not really a subject broached by high school or (in general) undergraduate students, and I can't speak to the image's pedagogical value (hence the mere comment).

Comment: I'm reading Remmert's Theory of Complex Functions. I have no picture, but, it is an art. Math, good math, is art. (someday, I want to be an artist)

Comment: @JamesS.Cook, I am agree with you that good maths is art. In fact "mathematical beauty" is really a kind of artistic beauty. Quoted from Halbeisen in his book, *Combinatorial Set Theory*: "*I tried to write this book like a piece of music, not just writing note by note, but using various themes or voices.*" See also: "DAVID J. BENSON: **Music: A Mathematical Offering.** Cambridge University Press, Cambridge (2007)"

Comment: Anything based upon fractals tends to make for both good art and good mathematical discussion.

Comment: How is the Goethe a square at all?  I see numbers there, but not math.

Comment: NYU Poly had a conference devoted to the mathematical connections with the Durer painting where many prominent mathematicians (Conway, Richard Stanley, Ziegler, etc.) spoke. The videos from these talks are available here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3glV75mhF0

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for your edit. See my additional remark.

Answer (score 12):

Some crazy mathematicians have managed to calculate the missing centre of the Escher artwork below.

[Go to their website to learn all about it.](http://escherdroste.math.leidenuniv.nl/)
They have some pretty cool animations of it.

Also, [this article](http://im-possible.info/english/articles/escher_printgallery/) gives a pretty good overview of the project.

[Here is a link](http://web.cortland.edu/jubrani/Escher%20-%20Sheila%20Haak.pdf) to a paper about Escher and symmetry.

[image: Original]

[image: Filled in]

Comment: Nice Example! Thanks!

Comment: This is just plain cool.

Answer (score 11):

Henderson & Taimina (2006) point out that models in hyperbolic geometry are aesthetically compelling, and that the artist M. C. Escher made us of this in a representation of infinity within his works:

> Repeating patterns on the sphere have an aesthetic appeal through
>   their simplicity and finiteness. However, in these various hyperbolic
>   models, the patterns have an aesthetic appeal for us because of their
>   connections with infinity--there are infinitely many such patterns and
>   each also draws us to the infinity at the edge of the disc, leaving
>   sufficient space for our imagination.
>   (p. 69)

[image: M.C. Escher's Circle Limit III (based on the Poincaré disc model)]
M.C. Escher's Circle Limit III *(based on the Poincaré disc model)*

Henderson, D. W., & Taimina, D. (2006). Experiencing meanings in geometry. In N. Sinclair, D. Pimm, & W. Higginson (Eds.), Mathematics and the aesthetic: New approaches to an ancient affinity (pp. 58–83). Springer Verlag.

Comment: You can find a similar image (and others) here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2437/is-there-an-image-for-you-that-epitomizes-mathematics

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Salvador Dali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvador_dali)'s 1954 [Crucifixion (Corpus Hypercubus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifixion_%28Corpus_Hypercubus%29) "deviates from traditional portrayals of the Crucifixion by depicting Christ on the polyhedron net of a hypercube [...]."  It could be used to introduce the idea of a fourth spatial dimension.

[image: Crucifixion (Corpus Hypercubus)]

From the Wikipedia entry:

> Instead of painting Christ on a wooden cross, Dalí depicts him upon the net of a hypercube, also known as a tesseract. The unfolding of a tesseract into eight cubes is analogous to unfolding the sides of a cube into six squares. The use of a hypercube for the cross has been interpreted as a geometric symbol for the transcendental nature of God. Just as God exists in a space that is incomprehensible to humans, the hypercube exists in four spatial dimensions, which is equally inaccessible to the mind. The net of the hypercube is a three-dimensional representation of it, similar to how Christ is a human form of God that is more relatable to people.

Comment: (+1) Nice Example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

MAA has a special interest group devoted to mathematics and the arts. Here is the link to its web page which includes galleries and resources:

http://sigmaa.maa.org/arts/exhibits.html

AMS sponsors an exhibit of mathematical art at the Joint Mathematical Meetings and here is a link for that and related things:

http://www.ams.org/mathimagery/

There is also an annual conference dealing with connections between mathematics and the arts which generates lots of materials both of research and pedagogical interest:

http://bridgesmathart.org/

Answer (score 3):

Since this question has been bumped up, I recently learned (via an AMS [**tweet**](https://twitter.com/amermathsoc/status/877617646635593728)) about the work done by Crockett Johnson -- best known as the creator and illustrator of *Harold and the Purple Crayon* -- at the intersection of "artistic works" and mathematics.

More information can be found in the write-up from [**Atlas Obscura**](http://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/crockett-johnson-math-art-paintings-harold-purple-crayon); here are two sample excerpts, along with images, that I found particularly interesting. The first is on the Pythagorean Theorem, and the second is on an alternative proof [to, among others, that of Archimedes] that the regular heptagon is constructible, which was published in a 1975 issue of *The Mathematical Gazette*:

> Johnson, C. (1975). A construction for a regular heptagon. *The Mathematical Gazette, 59*(407), 17-21.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at many of [these](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~mqed/eBookshelf/art/index.php) in a while, but there are several links to the math behind patterns, perspective, etc.

Comment: (+1) Surely perspective is one of the most important mathematical aspects of paintings. Do you have any particular example to introduce here? Please add its picture if it is possible.

Comment: Rennaissance paintings are the usual examples.  Some actually have pencil lines visible to see how the artist did the math.  Also it was really a development at that time.  So fits into a discussion (similar to the learnings on anatomy by dissection for art purpose).  see here for a few:  https://www.google.com/search?q=perspective+renaissance&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6lryy59nUAhWqAcAKHRCtA7MQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=628

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example to show how beautiful math is.

http://touch-geometry.karazin.ua/sitemap

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Popular fractal images (paisley looking things.)

Also this is maybe more applied math or data science, but a lot of the Edward Tufte book images are compelling.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte#/media/File:Minard.png

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octacube_(sculpture)

Also check out the woodcuts for De re Metallica.

Comment: Link-only answers really don't work well here. Mind adding the image with attribution, and perhaps a few sentences?